# How do i set the height of the FollowCamera in Unreal

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4, unreal-engine5

I'm using the following code to set the height of the follow camera but it does not work

```
CameraBoom =
    CreateDefaultSubobject<USpringArmComponent>
    (TEXT("CameraBoom"));
CameraBoom->SetupAttachment(RootComponent);
CameraBoom->TargetArmLength = 300.0f;
CameraBoom->SetRelativeLocation(FVector(0.0f, 0.0f, 300.0f));
CameraBoom->bUsePawnControlRotation = true;



FollowCamera =
    CreateDefaultSubobject<UCameraComponent>
    (TEXT("FollowCamera"));
FollowCamera->SetupAttachment(CameraBoom,
    USpringArmComponent::SocketName);
```

What do I change to set camera height

Comment: Please don't tag unrelated languages like C. Then please don't tag multiple engine versions, you target only one version so pick that and remove the other (this will also narrow down the possible solutions and answers to the ones that are relevant for you).